# append + trigger("create") really slow with large DOM in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm using Phonegap and JQuery Mobile to create an iPhone mobile application. This application parses an external JSON and its contents are "formatted" in the Javascript appending the corresponding HTML tags and then adding all of this to the DOM. This is done with the following:

```
$('div#container').empty().append(output).trigger("create");
```

The variable output being a string with all the JSON with the additional HTML tags.

The previous code works perfectly when the data in the JSON is small and therefore the contents in the output variable is also small, but when the data is large and the output variable has a large string defined (with approximately 80 HTML tags) that line takes almost 30 seconds to execute on the iPhone (it works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and Safari). However if I remove the trigger method, the information is shown instantly, but of course without any styling applied:

```
$('div#container').empty().append(output);
```

Is there any way to solve this to reduce the execution time?

Comment: Why do you need to use trigger?what's the point?

Comment: I use it to apply the style to the new elements added to the DOM.

Comment: Did you try to apply the style for new elements(output) using simple way like $(output).css(...).(processing is here)

Comment: It's not just adding CSS styles, when using .trigger("create") JQM adds additional DOM elements to apply the necessary styling.